# Bash - Pattern matching an argument against the timestamp format

Tags: regex, bash, format, timestamp, date-formatting

I have a script that is supposed to take in as input a timestamp of the format:

```
YYYY-mm-dd HH:mi:ss
```

I use the following to check if the input conforms to the pattern:

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" && "$2" == '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}' ]]
```

If it does not match the pattern, it is supposed to throw an error. I turned on bash logging, and passed the following as input:

```
./meta_script_test.sh -r '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

The log that is generated by the `bash -x` declaration shows this:

```
 [[ 2014-01-01 00:00:00 == \[\0\-\9\]\{\4\}\-\[\0\-\9\]\{\2\}\-\[\0\-\9\]\{\2\}\ \[\0\-\9\]\{\2\}\:\[\0\-\9\]\{\2\}\:\[\0\-\9\]\{\2\} ]]
+ usage 'Timestamp is in an improper format. Please enter it as: YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00, and try again'
+ cat
    Usage: ./meta_script_test.sh -r 'timestamp'

    -r for reset is used to manually pass a date in timestamp format in case of data corruption for creating the delta table.

    Example: ./meta_script_test.sh -r '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I have tried various combinations of the if statement like:

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" && "$2" == '\[0-9]{4}-\[0-9]{2}-\[0-9]{2} \[0-9]{2}:\[0-9]{2}:\[0-9]{2}' ]]
```

And

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" && "$2" == '\(d){4}-\(d){2}-\(d){2} \(d){2}:\(d){2}:\(d){2}' ]]
```

Nothing seems to be working. Can you please point me to the right regex for matching the parameter correctly to the timestamp format? Thanks!

Comment: `==` tests against file glob patterns. Use `=~` to test against a regexp.

Comment: @Barmar: I'd done that too. No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=~` to perform a regular expression match. `==` is for exact matches or matching a file globbing pattern. The regexp shouldn't be quoted; since your regexp contains a space, you need to escape or quote that character.

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" && "$2" =~ [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} ]]
```

Comment: Now I get: `+ [[ 2014-01-01 00:00:00 =~ \[0-9]\{4}-\[0-9]\{2}-\[0-9]\{2} \[0-9]\{2}:\[0-9]\{2}:\[0-9]\{2} ]]
+ usage 'Timestamp is in an improper format. Please enter it as: YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00, and try again'
+ cat
        Usage: ./meta_script_test.sh -r 'timestamp'

        -r for reset is used to manually pass a date in timestamp format in case of data corruption for creating the delta table.`

        Example: ./meta_script_test.sh -r '2014-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: You're a life saver! I've spent about 2 hours just trying to figure out what the hell was wrong with it! Thank you so much! :)